# mod $p$ homology of Thom spectra MSU

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, homology, cobordism, steenrod-algebra

Using pairing in Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence one can show that homology of $BU(n)$ is a free abelian group with basis $\alpha_{k_1}\cdots\alpha_{k_t}$, $k\leqslant n$, where $\alpha_{i} = \big((c_1)^i\big)^* \in H_{2i}(\mathbb C P^\infty)$. Therefore, passing to (co)limits and applying the Thom isomorphism, we have
\begin{equation}
H_*(MU) \cong \mathbb Z[a_1, a_2, \ldots].
\end{equation}

Since polynomial generators come as image of homology classes of $\mathbb C P^\infty$, $\mathfrak A_p^*$-comodule structure of $H_*(MU; \mathbb F_p)$ can be deduced from the one of $H_*(\mathbb C P^\infty; \mathbb F_p)$.

Is there any similar description of $H_*(MSU; \mathbb F_p)$?

**UPD.**

Let $S = \mathbb F_p[x_n| n+1\neq p^t]$.
Define $f\colon H_*(MU;\mathbb F_p) \to S$ by the formula
\begin{equation*}
 f(a_n) =
  \begin{cases}
  x_n;\quad&\text{if $n+1 \neq p^t$;}
  \\
  0;&\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then the composition
\begin{equation*}
 H_*(MU;\mathbb F_p)
 \xrightarrow{\text{coaction}}
 \mathfrak A_p'\otimes_{\mathbb F_p} H_*(MU;\mathbb F_p)
 \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}\otimes f}
 \mathfrak A_p'\otimes_{\mathbb F_p} S
\end{equation*}
is an isomorphism of $\mathbb F_p$-algebras and $\mathfrak A_p^*$-comodules.
Here $\mathfrak A_p' = \mathbb F_p[\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots]$ is the quotient of 
the dual Steenrod algebra $\mathfrak A_p^*$.

The Adams' paper *Primitive Elements in the $K$-theory of $BSU$*
contains a computation of homology $H_*(BSU; \mathbb Z)$.
Namely, $H_*(BSU; \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[y_2, y_3, \ldots]$, $\deg y_i = 2i$.
And therefore, $H_*(MSU; \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[Y_2, Y_3, \ldots]$, $\deg Y_i = 2i$.
But still the proof does not describe the embedding
\begin{equation*}
 H_*(MSU; \mathbb Z) \hookrightarrow H_*(MU; \mathbb Z).
\end{equation*}

Are there any explicit formulae for the images of $y_n$ in $H_*(MU)$?
I would be really grateful for something explicit that could be useful
for describing the $\mathfrak A_p^*$-comodule structure of $H_*(MSU;\mathbb 
F_p)$.

Comment: Basically you can play the same game at odd prime.  I don't know about the explicit $F_p$ algebra structure, but $A_p$ commodule structure at odd prime is quite simple, and at 2, it is described in (1.5) of The Homotopy Type of MSU
David J. Pengelley
American Journal of Mathematics
American Journal of Mathematics
Vol. 104, No. 5 (Oct., 1982), pp. 1101-1123

Comment: @user43326, is there any reference to $A_p^*$-comodule structure of $H_*(MSU;\mathbb F_p)$ for odd $p$?

Comment: I don't have any reference, but at odd $p$, $MSU$ splits as wedge of $BP$, this gives the action of the Steenrod algebra.

Comment: @user43326 do you how to prove the latter?

Comment: Well, Pengalley says, "standard method"... I would imagine you can simply compute it using the Thom isomorphism.  Although there might be an argument using the fact that both $MSU$'s homotopy and homology are torsion-free.

Comment: @user43326 of course we need to compute homology of $MSU$ using the Thom isomorphism. But the Thom isomorphism just reduces to the case of homology of $BSU$, whose comodule structure is still not so easy to compute

Comment: Well, the point is that "Wu's formula" or whatever it is called, may make sometimes the action of the Steenrod algebra on homology of Thom spectrum easier to compute than that on the homology of the base space.

Comment: user43326 all your hints are well known. Could you, please, write down explicit formulae? Probably you know that it is really difficult to describe the action of $\mathfrak A_p$ on the Chern classes, even using Wu's formula. Indeed it is easy to describe the action on the Chern roots, but after that you should rewrite the result in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials (Chern classes). Nevertheless, using the action on $\mathcal C P^\infty$ you can describe COaction on homology of $\mathcal C P^\infty$ and therefore of $MU$.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get this right.  The fact that it is the wedge of $BP$ gives the comodule structure in "coordinate free" way, or as abstract comodule over $A_p$.  But maybe you are after "explicit" coaction with a chosen basis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105526/discussion-between-semyon-abramyan-and-user43326).